# How can i use 2 connection string using OR condition Web.config in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-config, web-config-transform

How can i use 2 connection strings with same connection string name

but differ in IP using OR condition  Web.config in asp.net

when any one fails other should respond.

**First  Connection string:**

add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source = **10.10.1.1\SQLEXPRESS** ; Database = stores; User ID = sa; pwd = ********" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

**Second Connection string:**

add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source = **10.10.1.2\SQLEXPRESS** ; Database = stores; User ID = sa; pwd = ********" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to add two connection strings, just add a fail over partner in connection string

> add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source =
>   10.10.1.1\SQLEXPRESS ; Failover Partner= 10.10.1.2\SQLEXPRESS ; Database = stores; User ID = sa; pwd = ********"
>   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Comment: Thank you sir i will try